# Interpreting fio test result

Tags: linux, iops, fio

I ran `fio` on a VM provided by my VPS provider and got this result:

```
$ fio --name=random-write --ioengine=posixaio --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --numjobs=1 --size=4g --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --time_based --end_fsync=1

[--- snipped ---]

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=86.8MiB/s (91.0MB/s), 86.8MiB/s-86.8MiB/s (91.0MB/s-91.0MB/s), io=6518MiB (6834MB), run=75080-75080msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sda: ios=0/278903, merge=0/29360, ticks=0/3652618, in_queue=3120276, util=42.54%
```

Is there a website with reference numbers so I can understand if the numbers I get are good/bad? For example, something saying that "HDD 10k RPM should have numbers between xxxx and yyy, SSD MLC should have numbers between aaaa and bbbb, and so on".

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about comparing value because maybe your provider manage disks  within RAID group, in that case and depends on the way they're managed, throughput may differs.

Maybe that kind of document may helps you (to get some throughput ideas)

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v2/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/innovationcentre/whitepapers/TCM0475A_ENG.pdf

Else, do you have any details on your VM disk configuration ?